# Bootstrap Collapse Accordion one panel open, all others close

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created two bootstrap accordions, one below the other. I did not like the way that the panels were awkwardly shifting locations when I had them all as one accordion, so I created two separate accordions. In doing so, each accordion works the way I would like: only one panel-body can be open at a time per accordion, but I would like to only allow one panel-body to be open..

To better explain what I mean...
Currently, you can have one panel-body opened in both the top and bottom row. I want you just to be able to have one opened at a time.

Is this possible to do?

Here is an example of what I have made
https://codepen.io/aahmed2/pen/yOQvVz

Here is my code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading  bites-stings" role="tab" id="headingSeven">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <h2>Bites and Stings</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="health-resources/mosquitoes.html"><h4>Mosquitoes</h4></a>
                <a href="health-resources/ticks.html"><h4>Ticks</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Bees and Wasps</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Animal Bites</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading pet-health" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                <h2>Pet Health and Safety</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>Pet Allergies</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Toxic Plants</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Pet and Wildlife Encounters</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading livestock-health" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                <h2>Livestock Health and Safety</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>This is a Topic</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Topic 2</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Another Topic</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading zoonotic" role="tab" id="headingFour">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                <h2>Zoonotic Diseases</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>Bacterial</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Fungal</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Parasitic</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Prionotic</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Rickettsial</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Spirochetes</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Viral</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading allergies" role="tab" id="headingFive">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                <h2>Allergies</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>Animal Allergies</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Environmental Allergies</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading environment-health" role="tab" id="headingSix">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
                <h2>Environmental Health</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>This is a Topic</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Topic 2</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Another Topic</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div><!--/collapse-->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have multiple accordions but only one open at the same time you just need to combine the `data-parent`. So I have made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyqKmp) for you to see it working.

I just changed all `data-parent` to `data-parent="#accordion,#accordion2"`

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading  bites-stings" role="tab" id="headingSeven">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion,#accordion2" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <h2>Bites and Stings</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="health-resources/mosquitoes.html"><h4>Mosquitoes</h4></a>
                <a href="health-resources/ticks.html"><h4>Ticks</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Bees and Wasps</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Animal Bites</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading pet-health" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion,#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                <h2>Pet Health and Safety</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>Pet Allergies</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Toxic Plants</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Pet and Wildlife Encounters</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading livestock-health" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion,#accordion2" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                <h2>Livestock Health and Safety</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>This is a Topic</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Topic 2</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Another Topic</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading zoonotic" role="tab" id="headingFour">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion,#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                <h2>Zoonotic Diseases</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>Bacterial</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Fungal</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Parasitic</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Prionotic</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Rickettsial</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Spirochetes</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Viral</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading allergies" role="tab" id="headingFive">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion,#accordion2" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                <h2>Allergies</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>Animal Allergies</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Environmental Allergies</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading environment-health" role="tab" id="headingSix">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion,#accordion2" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
                <h2>Environmental Health</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#"><h4>This is a Topic</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Topic 2</h4></a>
                <a href="#"><h4>Another Topic</h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div><!--/collapse-->

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @Abbey you are welcome, don't forget to accept the answer to help future users of SO.

Comment: this works great in everything but Internet Explorer. Is there a way to make it work the same in iE as it does in Chrome? Here is the link to the codepen http://codepen.io/aahmed2/pen/yOQvVz