# Force open minimum one accordion bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking for the same following solution. I wanted to add more in this example but unable to comment due to low reputation points so adding here

[Bootstrap Collapse Accordion one panel open, all others close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054280/bootstrap-collapse-accordion-one-panel-open-all-others-close)

I want in this example that one tab always should be open. There are following tabs in the above example given in the link
Bites and Stings
Pet Health and Safety
Livestock Health and Safety,
etc.

So if i click on "Livestock Health and Safety" it opens this tab and then click on "Pet Health and Safety" it opens this and close the "Livestock Health and Safety".

So my question is if i click again on the same tab it should not closed. i.e. One always should be in open state.

Hope it clears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this pen: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/gsvnanoop/pen/RRxNkw)

What I have done is add the following javascript to the code.

```
$('.panel-heading a').on('click',function(e){
   if($(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.